# Segmentation Fault while reading JSON parse to NSArray in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, compilation

There is a method used to fill realm database from json:

```
func parseJSON(data: NSData) -> NSArray? {
    do {
        let array: NSArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray

        return array
    } catch _ {
        return nil
    }
}
//parameter came from previous method
func updateDatabaseFromParsedJson(parsedJson: NSArray) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }
    for i in 0..<parsedJson.count {
        let deviceObject = parsedJson[i]

        let name = deviceObject["name"] as! String
        let id = deviceObject["id"] as! Int

        var device = Device()
        device.name = name
        device.id = id
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(device)
        }
        var deviceMeasuresArray = deviceObject["measures"] as! NSArray
        for i in 0..<deviceMeasuresArray.count {
            var measureObject = deviceMeasuresArray[i]
            var measure = Measure()
            measure.slug = measureObject["name"]
            measure.device = device
            measure.localize()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(measure)
            }
            var measureEntriesArray = measureObject["averages"] as! NSArray
            for i in 0..<measureEntriesArray.count {
                var entryObject = measureEntriesArray[i]
                var entry = PeriodAverage()
                entry.measure = measure
                entry.value = entryObject["value"]
                entry.start = NSDate.parse(entryObject["start"])
                entry.end = NSDate.parse(entryObject["end"])
                entry.length = entryObject["length"]
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(entry)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension NSDate {
    class func parse(dateString: String) -> NSDate {

        let format = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
    }
}
```

JSON itself http://188.166.51.200/api/v1/actual_data/

While compiling I get error `Error:unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11`

Where I am wrong and how to properly parse my json? I think problem is in lines where json fields forcely parsed to objects but I am new in swift and can't exactly determine the error.

Comment: While compiling or while the application is running? You need to narrow down where is your issue exactly. You can use breakpoints for that, or add logs to know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've apparently run across a compiler issue (which you should [report to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com)), although it's easy enough to work around.  If you're using `Swift` you should really be using `Swift` collection types instead `Foundation` collection types if possible (i.e., `Array` instead of `NSArray`) which allow for more type information.  Also, while you're casting some of the values you're getting out of your JSON, you're not casting them all.  Adding this additional type information will make the compiler behave and work around the issue.  I would suggest the following edit:

```
func updateDatabaseFromParsedJson(parsedJson: Array<AnyObject>) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.deleteAll()
    }
    for i in 0..<parsedJson.count {
        let deviceObject = parsedJson[i] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        let name = deviceObject["name"] as! String
        let id = deviceObject["id"] as! Int

        var device = Device()
        device.name = name
        device.id = id
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(device)
        }
        var deviceMeasuresArray = deviceObject["measures"] as! Array<AnyObject>
        for i in 0..<deviceMeasuresArray.count {
        var measureObject = deviceMeasuresArray[i] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            var measure = Measure()
            measure.slug = measureObject["name"] as! String // I'm guessing on the type here
            measure.device = device
            measure.localize()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(measure)
            }
            var measureEntriesArray = measureObject["averages"] as! Array<AnyObject>
            for i in 0..<measureEntriesArray.count {
                var entryObject = measureEntriesArray[i] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                var entry = PeriodAverage()
                entry.measure = measure
                entry.value = entryObject["value"] as! String // Guessing on the type here also
                entry.start = NSDate.parse(entryObject["start"] as! String)
                entry.end = NSDate.parse(entryObject["end"] as! String)
                entry.length = entryObject["length"] as! String // Again, guessing on the type here
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.add(entry)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unrelated to the compiler issue, you could also use for-in loops to make your code more `Swift` like.  You can read more about them in the [For-In Loops](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121) section of the [Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) chapter of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/).